# stof_doctrine_extensions can't load in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I'm trying to do a "soft-delete" for a symfony project. So i want to use StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle and i did :

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            ...
            softdeleteable: true

doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```

In my config.yml.

But now i have the error message:

> Unrecognized option "softdeleteable" under
>   "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.filters"

Comment: Did you complete step 2 of installation? https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html

Comment: @Veas I did and it says : ClassNotFoundException

Comment: you need to configure the AppKernel adding the new BundleClass

Comment: I just installed everything without any problem. Doublecheck everything, clear cache

Comment: @Matteo I did. May be i did something wrong. I just wrote : `new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),` in my AppKernel.php

Comment: very strange. Double check if the file exists in `./vendor/stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.php`  in order to verify the composer installation was fine

Comment: @Veas @Matteo i dont think it's normal but when i do `composer require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle` i'v got error mssage     - The requested package gedmo/doctrine-extensions (locked at v2.4.28, required as dev-master) is satisfiable by gedmo/doctrine-extensions[v2.4.28] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: oh exactly, the dependency of your project aren't good with the bundle, please post your `composer.json` file in order to debug the problem

Comment: @Matteo the "require" part ?

Comment: @Matteo it's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the error message you post seems you put the key `filters` under `entity_managers` key (as message says: `under "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.filters"`). fix moving the filters section under the `orm` key, as example:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```

Hope this help